# Given a pointer to a container, how would I add an item to it?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, insertion

I'm trying to create an array which holds a pointer to a container at each element. The container is of type Queue and is basically a linked list queue. I want to add an item to the linked list at a given index but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is the array being initialized:

```
Queue<string> * table;

table = new Queue<string>[tableSize];
```

This is what I want (I know it doesn't work):

```
table[5] = "SomeString";
```

I've tried:

```
Queue<string> *ptr = table[5];
ptr->insert(SomeString);
```

Comment: You can always dereference it: `(*table)[5] = "somestring"` or `table[0][5] = "somestring"`

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to create an array which holds a pointer to a container at each element.

For a local array:

```
Queue<string> *table[tableSize];
```

For a heap-allocated array:

```
Queue<string> ** table;
table = new Queue<string>*[tableSize];
```

Use either one the same:

```
table[5]->insert("Some String");
```

But, I advise you to ditch the naked pointers and the manual allocation. Use `std::vector<Queue<string>>`:

```
std::vector<Queue<string>> v(tablesize);
v[5].insert("Some String");
```